# Accessing a specific row by using data-attr against a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-modal

Im trying to display a modal based on what row the user clicks on, the data attribute field is set from the existing entries in the database. I then need the data of that row to be displayed in the modal itself.

Here is my table before you click..

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered">

                <?php
                $list = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM notes WHERE memberid = '$membersid'");

                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($list); 

                if($rows == 0)
                {
                    ?><th id="no-notes">No Existing Notes</th><?php
                }
                else
                {?>
                    <tr>
                    <th id="note-h-date">Date</th>
                    <th id="note-h-excerpt">Excerpt</th>
                    <th id="note-h-addedby">Added By</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    if($list)
                    {
                        while($listnotes = mysqli_fetch_array($list))
                        {
                            $dateadded = new DateTime($listnotes['dateadded']);

                            ?><tr class="clickable table-sel" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $listnotes['id'];?>" data-target="#noteModal"><?php
                            echo "<td class='note-dateadded'>".$dateadded->format('d-m-Y')."</td>";
                            echo "<td class='note-excerpt'>".substr($listnotes['note'],0,95)."...</td>";
                            echo "<td class='note-addedby'>".$listnotes['addedby']."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    }
                }


                ?>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Here is the modal code.

```
<!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="noteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <?php
                    $noteid = $_SESSION['noteid'];

                    $check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id = '$noteid'");
                    if($check){

                        $chkres = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
                        $dateadded = new DateTime($chkres['dateadded']);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Failed to load note";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Note dated: <?php echo $dateadded->format('d-m-Y');?></h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="fullnote"><?php echo $chkres['note'];?></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

JQuery as orginally was trying to set it as a session variable and use that to then access the correct data from the database.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $(".clickable").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.post("modal-post.php",{"nid": value});
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Any help would be great. Explanations probably not great and I do apologise.

Comment: what issue you are facing right now? is this `alert(value)` not appearing?

Comment: Sorry, I used the alert to confirm that the correct data-attr value was set when the user clicked on specific table row. I then need to use that value within the modal window and access the correct note content

Comment: is this `noteModal` is coming back as a response of `modal-post.php`? Or its already present in your page?

Comment: noteModal is present in the current html page. The only response from the modal-post.php would be setting a session variable, which it doesnt.

Comment: if you are setting something to SESSION with ajax and excpecting to take the value from SESSION without any reload is no good

Comment: here is the logic which need to be followed. PHP is a server side technology so noteModal which is already in your page will have wrong or blank value for `noteid` variable. So to tweak this; on page load modal related HTML should not come. Then on `click`, pass the `nid` and modify `modal-post.php` to get back entire modal related HTML with correct information according to passed parameter. Now in ajax `success` bind the returned HTML to DOM and call `$('#noteModal').modal('show');` to show the modal dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed to solve my problem with the feedback from you guys and delving a little deeper.

So here is the sorted code.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="noteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="15" id="fullnote"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery -> Ajax Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "modal-post.php", //URL here
                data: { param: value },
                dataType: 'json',
                }).done(function( data ) {
                     $('#myModalLabel').html("Date Added: " + data.notedate);
                     $('#fullnote').html(data.note);
            });
    });
});
```

Then finally the PHP script.

```
$nid = $_POST['param'];

include("connection.php");
$check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id = '$nid'");
if($check){
    $chkres = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
    $dateadded = new DateTime($chkres['dateadded']);
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            "notedate"=>$dateadded->format('d-m-y'),
            "note"=>$chkres['note']
        )
    );
}
else
{
    echo "Failed to load note";
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have error. in the modal page, instead of:

```
 $noteid = $_SESSION['noteid'];
```

you should have

```
 $noteid = $_POST['nid'];
```